# Accidentally used 3.6 volt battery for my mouse, now it only works with 3.6 volt

Tags: voltage, batteries, mouse

My mouse requires AA 1.5 volt batteries to work. I accidentally used a 3.6 volt Li-SOCl2 battery. Now it works fine with the 3.6 volt battery but doesn't work at all with a 1.5 volt AA battery.

I have this mouse and keyboard combi:
https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-nz/products/keyboards/sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/l5v-00027

How is this even possible?

Perhaps some traces are burnt enough so that no current can flow through them with 1.5 volt?

Comment: If you would burn a trace, an additional 2 V over what's specified would not be enough. We can only guess, but some front-end LDO could be toast and you are now feeding it though some body diode. You need to open it and probe it to find out.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the design, what really happened can only be guessed at.

I'm assuming that the mouse originally worked with only **one** 1.5 V AA cell, I mean, that it did not require **two** cells in series.

You probably damaged the DCDC boost converter chip inside the mouse. This boost converter is needed as 1.5 V usually isn't enough to power all circuits. This is an example of a typical boost converter circuit:

[image]

Note the inductor L1 and the diode D1, they are nearly always present in boost converters. It is possible that D1 is an internal (on chip) transistor with a diode in parallel.

If the IC is damaged and doesn't switch but L1 and D1 are intact then applying 3.6 V at the input will result in about 3 V at the output. That could be enough to power all circuits and make the mouse operate.